# Pagination at top and bottom with DataTables

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

I'm using SB Admin 2 theme, with DataTables jQuery plugin. Is it possible to have pagination positioned at the **top** and at the **bottom** of a table, **at the same time**? If it is, how could I achieve it? This is what I currently have as a working code:

```
<script>

$('#data-table').DataTable({
  responsive: true,
  "pageLength": 25,
  "columnDefs": [ {
  "targets"  : 'no-sort',
  "orderable": false,
  }],
  "language": {
          "lengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ items per page",
          "zeroRecords": "Nothing found. Please change your search term",
          "info": "Page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
          "infoEmpty": "No results",
          "infoFiltered": "(filtered out of _MAX_)",
    "search":       "Search:",
    "paginate": {
      "first":      "First",
      "last":       "Last",
      "next":       ">>",
      "previous":   "<<"
    }
  }
});

</script>
```

I have tried using what the official site [suggests](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dom_multiple_elements.html) (removing the code I posted, and then doing a simple copy/paste, and changing the id), but it did absolutely nothing. I'm guessing that I'm doing something wrong, but I have no idea what.

Comment: Take a look to this example: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dom_multiple_elements.html and there is the documentation about the `dom` option: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#sDom

Comment: Can you explain where you want pagination to appear at the top - between page length and search control, on the new line, etc?

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ: That was the first thing I checked. I have tried c/p it in my code, and changing the id to that of my table, but nothing happened.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com The pagination should appear on the right, just above the table, since the one on the bottom appears on the right as well.

Comment: What about search box, since that's where it is - on the right?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Ah, you're right. I guess I'd move them both to the middle, then. Sorry, I've been at this for a few hours, and it's becoming irritating.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Bootrsap-based styling such as with SB Admin 2 theme requires specially crafted value for [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option. Default value for [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) with Bootstrap is shown below:

```
dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>>" +
     "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
     "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
```

Pagination control is represented by letter `p` in the `dom` value.

You can put pagination at the top by using the code below. You can adjust column sizes or remove certain controls by adjusting the value for `dom` option.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-3'f><'col-sm-6'p>>" +
         "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
         "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1st47fpu/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: That did the trick! Not only that, but I fiddled about with the code you posted, and the stuff I had, and it seems to work very well together. :) I'll keep changing the parameters, and see what each of them does exactly. Thank you for the explanation, as well!

Comment: any idea how to do in angularjs

Comment: @Sana I haven't really used AngularJS, but this was one of the first results when I googled: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome Hope it helps.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Can we add custom class name or id of this define div tags??

Comment: @MitaliPatel, yes, please see [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom#Markup) option - Markup in the documentation. Use `<'class'>` or `<'#id'>` or `<'#id.class'>` for your custom div tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-3'f><'col-sm-6'p>>" +
         "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
         "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
});
```

This Solution Work for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).